# Creating Rules for a Firestore Database Structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an online gallery using Firebase Firestore for authentication and storage.

The application currently has users who will be able to create a gallery, and then add or remove images from the gallery.

The current structure is set up as galleries -> galleryId -> ( specific gallery info included here), there is a picture attached for a more detailed description

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVdoE.png)

Currently, all users are able to access, add and update all galleries.

1. Given the app structure, what rules should I set such that user A will only be able to perform reading, writing, updating, and deleting content on galleries they create?
2. Would there be a better way to lay out the collections and documents for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Given the app structure, what rules should I set such that user A will only be able to perform reading, writing, updating, and deleting content on galleries they create?

If you want to grant access to `/galleries/galleryId` only to the users that are owners of the gallery, then please use the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /galleries/{galleryId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;
    }
  }
}
```

> 2. Would there be a better way to lay out the collections and documents for this purpose?

No, that's a common way of doing that.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Hi there :) 

Just gave it a try and Yes that seems to correctly restrict the permissions! Thanks very much!